# How to make area for scan barcode using library Zbar more smaller android

Tags: android, resize, barcode

I using this library `https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner` for my app. Everything worked fine. But i want make some modified which is make area for scan barcode more smaller. I want resize the area scan. This image show default size for area scan. [image]

The box area scan. How can i make it more smaller box area or resize ? Sorry i don't have modified code yet because i stuck how can i resize it.

I want like left side image which is no 1. The smaller height compare to image no 2 (right side). For width is ok, never mind. Just for the height only.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to make it square ?

Comment: The library have no such method to resize the scanner view.

Comment: @Piyush I want make the height more smaller. You see red line in the image ? maybe i want the height between top and red line.. mean smaller than default.. You got what i mean ?

Comment: i update question. i add image for more clear.